# Fire and Forget in java using HttpAsyncClients

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to use HTTPAsyncCLient for fire and forget in my app.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/

I am following this example given here:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.0.x/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchange.java

My Code looks like this:

```
           CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
           httpclient.start();
           HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
           Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(request, null);
          /*try {
            HttpResponse resp = future.get();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            String fr = sb.toString();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }*/
       httpclient.close();
```

If I uncomment the commented part, everything works. 
But what I want to do is a fire and forget request. So, when I comment out the part as above, the HTTP request is not made.
Any idea what I am doing wrong? What should I do for a fire and forget request?

Comment: Since you do not force the future in the commented-out state, it is very possible that the httpclient.close() is executed before the request is even send, let alone completed. Have you tried breaking in the close line? Can you observe the request if trapped in this breakpoint?

Comment: You are right. If I break on httpclient.close(), the request is received on the server. So I understand the problem. How do we make it fire and forget then?

Answer (score 1):

Your httpclient instance cannot be closed until the request is complete.

While I am not certain, I would suggest

```
// ONCE
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
httpclient.start();


// for every fire and forget request
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
httpclient.execute(request, null);`
```

keep your client alive between requests, so no calling close (reuse the instance instead)

Comment: I can not restart my tomcat without calling `close()`. Is there any place to invoke it?